# How can I create an instance variable to all instances of the class in ruby, using metaprogramming?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, metaprogramming

I'm new to ruby/rails world, and I'm facing and issue that appears to be something trivial, but it isn't being that easy for me.

What I want to do, is to write a simple helper method, to help keep the controllers clean. This method will receive a symbol/string, and create an instance variable with the camelized received string, which will evaluate to a constant/class.

My attempts resume themselves to this:

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base

  ...

  protected

  def self.service(name)
    instance_eval do
      instance_variable_set("@#{name.to_s.pluralize}", name.to_s.camelize.constantize)
    end
  end
```

And, in my controller:

```
class UserController < ApplicationController

  service :user
```

But when I do this, it create the instance variables in `UserController`, not `UserController.new`. So, I know what is wrong, but I couldn't find how can I do this right.

Can anyone help me with that?

Comment: Did you try defining this method without `self.` and calling it with `before_action :service` instead with `service :user`?

Comment: I guess I could do that, but this `service` method won't create just one service. I want each controller to specify services it needs. Can I do that with `before_action`?

Comment: As I think, there is no way you will need all controllers for one request, so something like this:
`before_action -> {|c| c.service(:user)}` and setting instance variable inside should be enough. What about class variable? (e.g. @@my_var)

Comment: As class variables change the state of all instances that inherit from the class, that may not work the way you expect.

Comment: By 'instances' I mean 'classes'. Sigh.

Answer (score 1):

The trouble is that this method is in the class scope:

```
  def self.service(name)
    instance_eval do
      instance_variable_set("@#{name.to_s.pluralize}", name.to_s.camelize.constantize)
    end
  end
```

This means it'll be setting class level instance variables - or class variables (kinda).

If you want to follow this approach, you'll need to store these all in an array or similar at the class level, which can be read out and turned into instance variables when the class is instantiated.

However, I don't like to mess with the initialize method on controllers. It's not the way to do things, so could change the class behaviour, break things or become fragile when changing versions.

In your ApplicationController, something like:

```
class << self
  def service(name)
    @services ||= []
    return @services += name.map(&:to_sym) if name.is_a?(Array)
    @services << name.to_sym
  end

  def service_names
    @services
  end
end

before_action :services

def services
  self.class.service_names.each do |name|
    instance_eval do
      instance_variable_set("@#{name.to_s.pluralize}", name.to_s.camelize.constantize)
    end
  end
end
```

This is untested.

Comment: Edited to fix class scoping cut & paste problem. Please let me know if it fails for any reason or if you want anything explained.